# assigning 2 variables from an array using an input?

Tags: python, arrays, variables

Trying to assign vdiv and hdiv with a choice from the array?

```
divOptions = [['|', '-'], ['4', '2'], ['v', 'h']]
divChoice = input('1 = |, - \n2 = 4, 2 \n3 = v, h \nPlease choose a number: ')
divInt = divOptions[divChoice - 1]
vdiv, hdiv = divInt
```

Comment: You need to convert `divChoice` to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
vdiv, hdiv = divInt[0], divInt[1]
```

And convert your input to an integer:

```
divChoice = int(input(...))
```